# How to improve the Speed of debugger attachment of Blackberry jde4.6 simulator?

Tags: blackberry, simulator, rim-4.6

I m working on Blackberry development when i click debug in the JDE my simulator takes long time to load the program and my desktop configuration are current configuration with 3GHZ processor and 4GB ram . I don't know why this happening ?

Comment: How long is a long time? Each time you start a simulator session the simulator simulates booting the device OS from a cold start. This does take time.

Comment: Actually after i run clean.bat in the simulator folder.It's takes long time to make a first boot.I knew that normally while making first boot it takes bit long time but in my system it takes nearly more than half on hour.

Comment: So far, I haven't found a way to speed up the debugger either. It's very irksome.

It takes a good 2-5 minutes to attach for me.

Answer (score 3):

From the official BlackBerry Developer Blog, here is a new post on setting up the simulator to boot as fast as possible.

[How-to Set up a Lightning Fast BlackBerry Smartphone Simulator](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-Developer-s-Blog/How-to-Set-up-a-Lightning-Fast-BlackBerry-Smartphone-Simulator/ba-p/320637#A101)

It's not an exact solution to this question as it doesn't specifically speed up the attaching of the debugger, but it should help with simulator startup time.